# weird page showed up when submitted an answer

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird page while submitting answers (might be the slow internet connection)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32850/weird-page-while-submitting-answers-might-be-the-slow-internet-connection)

When I submitted an answer on SO I got a blank page with

"Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan"

on the top.  There was nothing else on the page.  What is it?  Why was it there?

Comment: Please do a search before asking a question. Searching for "little slab of meat" here on Meta shows that this has been asked many times.

Comment: Perhaps the many times this has been asked is an indicator the page comes up too often...